# How to deal with the remaining elements in sliding window smoothing?

Tags: algorithm, sliding-window, lowpass-filter

I am implementing a sliding window as a LPF to smooth my data.

As long as I have a window size of `W`, my final `W` elements (window slides from the beginning to the end) or first `W` elements (window slides from the end to beginning) will not be able to smoothed.

How does one deal with them?

Is there a good way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Every kind of filter will shorten your data. Consider it shorter but better!

One tip I can offer is if you have an index, consider trimming each side by `W/2`, rather than chopping `W` off the front or back. This way is more accurate, because your new index reflects the smoothing.